# rfc822 curly brace / gmail in Dsync

Tags: gmail, curly-braces, rfc822

I am now using Dsync, an ipaas.

I want to send a message with gmail from another source(JIRA).

Since Dsync supplies auto curly braces in body, I cannot follow the rfc822 format just like below.

```
From: example <fromex.gmail.com>
To: exampleto <toex.gmail.com>
subject: subject example

this is plain body. no need attachment function.
```

instead, Dsync supply them with curly braces like below.

```
{
From: example <fromex.gmail.com>
To: exampleto <toex.gmail.com>
subject: subject example

this is plain body. no need attachment function.
}
```

is there any way to send gmail or rfc822 with curly braces?
or with headers. 
thanks.

Comment: Oh, or any other message format which uses curly braces would be very appreciated. Thanks again